# Error Connecting to Business Data Connectivity Metadata Store - SharePoint 2010 Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, business-data-catalog

Issue connecting to External Content Types in SharePoint Designer. After clicking on the ECT Site Objects on the Left side of the screen, it displays all the previously set up ECTs. When trying to access the settings and configurations of the content types it does not open properly and it displays the following message. Attempts to create a new test ECT does not work and displayed the same message. All production external lists work appropriately across the farm and are updating the databases properly. These are all SQL database ECTs. Anyone know how to fix this issue?
I have Farm Admin access and Metadata store has me as full permissions.

[image: Error from SPD]